# How to set title and publish content created by the transmogrifier folders section?

Tags: plone, data-migration, transmogrifier

I'm using [collective.transmogrifier.sections.folders](https://github.com/collective/collective.transmogrifier/blob/master/docs/source/sections/folders.rst) pipeline section to create parent folders of content I'm importing into Plone.

My problem is those folders are created without a title and are not being published.

How can I solve that?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this sections to your pipeline (you may already have the second one):

```
# Publish all folders 
[publish_all_folders]
blueprint = collective.transmogrifier.sections.inserter
key = string:_transitions
value = string:publish
condition = python:item.get('_type') == "Folder"

# Actually run the given transition to update the workflow state
[workflowupdater]
blueprint = plone.app.transmogrifier.workflowupdater
```

Comment: that won't work on a second iteration when folders are already created; I'll test now creating content all over again. seems to me a similar approach can be used for the title.

Comment: Ah, oops - forgot about the title.  I do wonder whether [sitewalker](https://github.com/collective/quintagroup.transmogrifier/blob/master/quintagroup/transmogrifier/sitewalker.py#L17) from qg.tm would be enough to kick start a 2nd iteration for you? (Note you can specify it to only bring back Folders) But it wouldn't know which title to add

Comment: I guess the title is just a capitalized id? otherwise you haven't said how it should be defined & you may have to fix it manually.